Can a server turn the traffic for multiple services from HTTP to HTTPS?
Ubuntu server with multiple services running on different ports other than 80 or 443.
When the server receives traffic on any of these services, how to make the traffic HTTPS instead of HTTP?
How can this be done on the application layer level and not using a firewall rule?
I tried using a reverse proxy, but only one service worked.

You should bind the services to the local loopback interface so that they are only accessible on localhost (e.g. 127.0.0.1:999, [::1]:999). Then, you add a reverse proxy in front of them that listens on the public interface and does the TLS termination.
You cannot have multiple reverse proxies on the exactly same address (e.g. https://example.com/) at the same time, but need to use different paths (e.g. /service1, /service2) or ports (e.g. https://example.com:8443/).

There sould be a directive in your webserver (if you are using a webserver) config to do that. If you use nginx as a webserver, this directive will do the trick:
server {
   listen 80;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

It opens a listener on port 80 (to accept HTTP traffic) and then translates the incomming request into a HTTPS call. The HTTPS call is on port 443, so traffic comming from port 443 is already HTTPS.

If i want traffic to http ://my domain.com:999 to be directed to https ://my domain.com:999, what should i write in nginx configuration file?

You can't; you need to do TLS and non-TLS on separate ports.

How can this be done?

It can't be done.


If i want traffic to http://example.com:999 to be directed to https://example.com:999, what should i write in nginx configuration file?

(I took that from the comment to the other answer, a I find it the best describing the problem you are trying to solve.)
What you need is the front-end service that can detect somehow whether the connection speaks HTTPS or plain HTTP and act accordingly. Common SSL/TLS libraries don't do this, and Nginx alone is not capable of doing it. That is what @vidarlo means when saying It can't be done.
There is a solution, but it can hardly be a reasonable business practice. You need to have a real reason to put this into production; if I was your supervisor and see such a solution I would really question your competence. Better design your systems that you don't need such fancy setups.
If you still want to play with it, you may get away with sslh sitting in front. It will detect whether the request is TLS (HTTPS) or non-TLS (plain HTTP), and it can "forward" these requests to appropriately configured web server ports. The web server then can do any redirects. For example, if the service must be available at port 999, sslh.cfg might be:
verbose: 0;
foreground: false;
inetd: false;
numeric: false;
transparent: true;
timeout: 2;
user: "sslh";
pidfile: "/var/run/sslh/sslh.pid";

listen:
(
    { host: "192.0.2.222"; port: "999"; }
);

protocols:
(
# Any TLS will go to Nginx port 443
     { name: "tls"; host: "localhost"; port: "443"; log_level: 0; },

# Everything else is going to Nginx port 80
     { name: "anyprot"; host: "localhost"; port: "80"; log_level: 0; }
);

The Nginx virtual host listening at localhost:443 must be configured with listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl; the Nginx virtual host listening at localhost:80 must be configured as listen 127.0.0.1:80 (also without any ssl on which is obsolete anyway) and it might send a redirect to https.
You can have multiple listen directives and/or multiple sslh instances running on different ports. Replace the fake IP address I used with your real IP address.
I suggest using transparent mode; it requires additional configuration and it's not that easy to setup correctly, but it makes Nginx to see and log real remote IPs instead of localhost, which is almost always desired.

nginx can handle TLS and non-TLS (in practice HTTPS and HTTP) on the same port, using ssl_preread in stream mode; there are numerous existing Q/As about this here, stackoverfow, and I think superuser also. But neither that nor your method changes HTTP to HTTPS, so I'm not sure it satisfies this Q.

Ok, I never used this directive, which is implemented by the module not built in by default. As for the Q, I find the question is awfully formulated, and the comment I extracted and cited in the front seems to be summing the real intention behind it. This answer perfectly address it. And, "the change of HTTP to HTTPS" (I think, it's about the url scheme), really means the redirect, for which there are much more numerous examples everywhere in the Internet, so I really don't think it needs further explanation.


Ubuntu server with multiple services running on different ports other than 80 or 443.

There is no solution which will work for any port - only the ports you explicitly configure.
The SSL (or more correctly, TLS) service cannot use the same IP address and port combination as the origin service (unless there is a multiplexing mechanism like that provided by HTTP - will come back to this). A typical pattern to address this is to restrict the origin service to the loopback interface, or run a port where external access is blocked by the firewall.
While you could use stunnel or similar to simply wrap the connection in SSL for designated ports I'd say you should be looking at a reverse proxy. Obvious candidates are nginx and haproxy. There are lots more, but I'd suggest sticking with nginx. The problems you are currently encountering and will encounter are not product specific and nginx is IMHO the easiest to provision.
A reverse proxy will allow you to multiplex traffic. You can route to a specific backend based on the host name (but the certificate management does not scale well unless you can provision wildcard certificates), port or the path from the incoming URL.
Mutliplexing based on ports also does not scale well - I would recommend doing this via the path. The complication here is that your origin servers will likely be expecting that they are at the apex of the path (/) but you need different paths for each one. That means you need to rewrite the path (not redirect!!!).
Hence within your nginx server definition for the TLS host you need something like:
location  /app1 {
  rewrite /app1/(.*) /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/ /app1/;
}

location  /app2 {
  rewrite /app2/(.*) /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:4444;
  proxy_redirect http://localhost:4444/ /app2/;
}
...

